# MATLAB tf command and exponentials

Tags: matlab, transfer-function

I must be missing something obvious but why does MATLAB have these two different behaviors?

Compare,

```
>> s = tf('s');
>> G = exp(-2.1*s)/(s+10)

G =
 
                  1
  exp(-2.1*s) * ------
                s + 10
 
Continuous-time transfer function.
```

with

```
>> G = exp(-2.1*s)+s

G =
 
  A = 
       x1  x2
   x1   1   0
   x2   0   1
 
  B = 
       u1
   x1   0
   x2  -1
 
  C = 
       x1  x2
   y1   1   0
 
  D = 
       u1
   y1   1
 
  E = 
       x1  x2
   x1   0   1
   x2   0   0
 
  (values computed with all internal delays set to zero)

  Internal delays (seconds): 2.1 
 
Continuous-time state-space model.
```

I understand the second model ends up being a DAE or implicit state space model ... but why? I couldn't find anything in the documentation. Other software like Mathematica doesn't seem to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The transfer function `exp(-tau*s)` represents a time delay where `tau` is the delay. Your second system cannot be represented in transfer function form. For clarity, if you let

```
s = tf('s');
G1 = exp(-2.1*s)/(s+10);
G2 = exp(-2.1*s)+s;
```

then `tf(G2)` returns

```
Error using DynamicSystem/tf
State-space models with internal delays cannot be converted to transfer function form.
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.- `F(s)=s` does not have inverse Laplace**

From the **MAT 04B Differential Equations** by W.Trench available [here](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Mission_College/MAT_04B_Differential_Equations_(Kravets)), in the [definition of the inverse of the Laplace transform](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Mission_College/MAT_04B_Differential_Equations_(Kravets)/07%3A_Laplace_Transforms/7.02%3A_The_Inverse_Laplace_Transform)

*[QUOTE]*

.. **we need ONLY consider the case where  degree(P)<degree(Q)** ..

*[END OF QUOTE]*

Where `F(s)=P(s)/Q(s)`

**2.- `f(t)=t;t>0` has Laplace transform**

`L(t)=1/s^2` for `s>0` but there's no Laplace transform `L(t)` for `s<0`.

The function `F(s)=s` does not have inverse Laplace.

It would have inverse Laplace if `s<0` had been included but the way the operator `L()` is defined confines forward transforms to `s>0` .

Therefore the values of `s`, the part of the `s` complex plane that would produce a function in time when attempting inverse Laplace transform of `F(s)=s` has already been excluded in the definition of the forward Laplace transform and MATLAB seems to know all this and excludes 's' as Laplace invertible.

**3.- Rewording**

Also, the **forward** **Laplace operator** applies the weight function `exp(-s*t)` integrating over `[0 Inf]` but the inverse Laplace operator has the following weight function : `exp(s*t)`

The integral `exp(s*t)*s` , as improper as it is, it remains so because it derails any integration attempt in an open interval, this is, with an `+Inf` on one side.

For `F(s)=exp(-2.1*s)` there is inverse Laplace because `exp(a*s)` can be Laplace inverted but only for certain values of `a`, which is when `exp(a*s)` has Taylor series that allow Laplace operator to go for each term, therefore `exp(-2.1*s)` can be Laplace inverted.

Adding a Laplace invertible function to one that is not spoils the whole pack.

Then, in a nutshell, with some distortion, but to get the idea through, MATLAB switches to State-Space functions, which can be considered a general case in which Laplace transform transfer functions are included.